# Displaying the ASCII Table Number for each item in a byte array

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a Message builder and in it I have to send a byte array to a remote machine requesting data.

I have an 8 bit number that counts how many items are being requested (count) and am trying to get the number inserted into a byte array.
The Byte array locations are in positions 70 & 71 of the array and in little endian order.

I am trying to just convert the byte and then insert the converted bytes with the following code.

```
    Dim count As Byte = 3
    Dim countbyteArray As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(count)
    sendBytes(70) = (countbyteArray(0))
    sendBytes(71) = (countbyteArray(1))
```

when I do this for anything greater than 1 it does not get accepted by the device I am sending the byte array to.

Am I in the right ball Park or completely wrong as I am not completely up to speed with Bytes and Bits. Also any example or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish by converting a `Byte` to a `Byte` array.  Can you explain?  What EXACTLY do those two positions in the `Byte` array that you send represent?  There actually is no overload of `BitConverter.GetBytes` that has a parameter of type `Byte` so what is actually happening there is that your `count` is being implicitly converted to an `Integer` and then you're getting a four-byte representation of that, which will just be three zeroes and your original value in least significant position.

Comment: The crux of this issue is exactly what your receiver is expecting and you haven't explained that to us and seemingly don't even understand it yourself, so what you need to do is research that.  We can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Little endian is the natural order in .NET so it is easy to work with.

As for a message builder, wouldn't it be easier to say

```
Dim message = New Message With { .Command = Command.Request, .Device = &hF, .Count = 8, .Filter = &h1234 }
Dim bytes = message.GetBytes()
' Hex for debugging
Dim hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes)
```

You just have to layout the structure of the message. One way is with `LayoutKind.Explicit`. I'd probably choose the LayoutKind that most closely aligns with the device documentation.

```
Public Enum Command As Byte
    Reset = 0
    Request = 1
End Enum

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
Public Structure Message
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public Command As Command
    <FieldOffset(1)> Public Device As Byte
    ' unused bytes default to 0
    <FieldOffset(10)> Public Count As UInt16
    <FieldOffset(12)> Public Filter As Int16

    Public Function GetBytes() As Byte()
        Dim rawData(0 To Marshal.SizeOf(Me) - 1) As Byte
        Dim handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Try
            Dim rawDataPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(Me, rawDataPtr, False)

            Return rawData
        Finally
            handle.Free()
        End Try
    End Function

End Structure

'TODO define enums, etc to make it easier for caller. 
'TODO update struct per device documentation
```